# On deletion of a post, SO should delete pending review queue items

Tags: bug, review-queues, deleted-questions

Today there was a red dot request for suggested edit review, where I was asked to review [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17918981) even though the [post had been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249025/convert-python-panadas-dataframe-to-list-of-tuples) by the OP hours before.  And, it was not an audit.

Perhaps the review queues could be shorter, or utilize scarce labor more effectively, if review items are "deleted" when a post is "deleted". "deleted" is in quotes, because nothing is really ever deleted on SO, so if the post is undeleted the review items could also be undeleted. Alternatively, if there is some value in editing or reviewing deleted items, that could be its own category, or if intermingled with active content, at least sorted to the back of the queue.

---

**Note:** As suggested by @animuson this may be a bug. It is not something I can reproduce but it is something that might be checked in op logs or similar tooling.

Comment: Review items already get invalidated automatically when the post gets deleted. I'm not sure why this particular one didn't - that would be a bug.

Comment: @animuson or caching.

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing occasionally, and it is very frustrating when you do run into it.  Doubly so if you've put effort into improving that which is being reviewed and turns out to be deleted.  I've not seen it recently — but I have seen it before.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123660/349538)

Comment: @Braiam Heck of a caching failure if that's the case. Question was [asked at](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47249025/timeline) 12:55. Edit was suggested at 12:57. Question was deleted at 13:22. Edit was approved at 17:07

Comment: Notice that DonaldDuck link was asked by animuson, which is hilarious.