# Deleted answer is appear on suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits, deleted-answers

When I review on suggested edit section I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18862134) which is already deleted. I don't understand why deleted answer is appear in suggested edit. Is this bug or I am missing some thing to understand.

Comment: old bug(?) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359234/on-deletion-of-a-post-so-should-delete-pending-review-queue-items and cross site https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/suggested-edits-to-posts-which-no-longer-exist-should-be-automatically-removed

Comment: Yeah, answer was deleted after edit was proposed